# oracle. order by clause and buffer gets(logical IO) count

Tags: oracle, sorting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdWHj.png)
[image]
table have 37 blocks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUweo.png)
[image]
select * from warehouses
-->  48  consistent gets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFoaY.png)
[image]
select * from warehouses order by 2
-->  38  consistent gets

please tell me Why difference?

Comment: Why does this matter?

Comment: no matter. just want to know reason(operation).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code as images - it prevents people using screen readers from getting the gist of your question, and it also makes proper indexing impossible. [Edit] your question and post the code as text (with proper formatting) instead.

Comment: Oracle's internals are not published to the extent required to account for every single consistent get.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the data is better clustered in the cache when it is retrieved ordered by column 2, thus requiring fewer reads.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two possible reasons for the difference.

First, **consistent gets** includes any gets performed by Oracle while parsing the query.  If you run each query twice and compare the results of the second run, you'll eliminate that source of discrepancy.

Second, the {order by 2} query means that the results are being fetched from the sort area.  Those fetches won't count as consistent gets, which is a main reason why the ordered query can have fewer gets reported.

You can play around with that second reason in SQL*Plus with

```
set arraysize nnnn;  <== nnnn is an integer
```

If you set the arraysize to match or exceed the number of rows; you'll get a very close if not exact match between the consistent gets for each query.

If you set the arraysize to 1 (careful if you have a lot of rows -- very slow!!!) you'll see a huge difference between the gets used.  The unordered query will have +1 get per row and the ordered query will not.